# Car Collision Script with Photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

Goal: Multiplayer collision physics! I have been trying to get this working for hours and I tried everything I could think of. I would like a car to move in the direction that it was struck by another car.

The car is a prefab with a (non-kinematic)rigidbody, so both GameObject's that are colliding have rigidbodies! Everything is being called correctly but the final result of the AddForce is not working the way I had hoped.

This is what I'm working with right now:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision!");
        Velocity = collision.relativeVelocity;
        Debug.Log(Velocity);
        NObjectHit = collision.transform.root.gameObject.name;
        Debug.Log(NObjectHit);
        photonView.RPC("CreateCollision", PhotonTargets.AllViaServer, Velocity, NObjectHit);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void CreateCollision(Vector3 velocity, string nobjecthit)
    {
        Debug.Log(nobjecthit + "RPC");
        rigid = GameObject.Find(nobjecthit).GetComponent(typeof(Rigidbody)) as Rigidbody;
        if (rigid != null)
        {
            rigid.AddForce(velocity * 1000);
            Debug.Log("Added Force");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which part is not working? Are all of your debug logs showing up as expected? Is it just the force that is not being transferred?

Comment: There are not errors in the console when run. When I hit one car into the other the car that is being hit doesn't move and the car that initiated the hit moves backwards.